# Android library not working after updating Gradle to version 3.1.1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library, android-studio-3.0

My Library is not working after updating gradle to 3.1.1. It's compiling, but when I try to run the project its giving me following error:

**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener not found**

I also observed in external libs that its not loading all dependencies related to my lib.

Any help would highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Here is the complete log file.

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\12.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\11.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 22 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\12.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\11.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 22 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform.transform(DesugarTransform.java:236)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:222)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:218)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\12.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\11.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 22 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:677)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:720)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform.transform(DesugarTransform.java:230)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\12.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\11.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 22 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar with arguments {--input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\12.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\11.jar --input C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --output C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\desugar\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\0.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\1.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\2.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\3.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\4.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\5.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\6.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\7.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\8.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\9.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\10.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\11.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\12.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\13.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\14.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\15.jar --classpath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\Downloads\PromptDemo\app\build\intermediates\transforms\stackFramesFixer\debug\16.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Users\gkondati\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\resources.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\rt.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jsse.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\jce.jar --bootclasspath_entry C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib\charsets.jar --min_sdk_version 22 --nodesugar_try_with_resources_if_needed --desugar_try_with_resources_omit_runtime_classes}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DesugarTransform.lambda$processNonCachedOnes$3(DesugarTransform.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:382)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
    ... 6 more
```

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
        options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
        options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Please post build.gradle file with versions of `gradle` and `firebase` plugins that you use

Comment: edited my post, check it, and i am not using any firebase related stuff.

Comment: I got the fix, its related to new gradle plugin version 4.0, you need to update your gradle maven lib to 2.0 to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your help, find out that its problem with new gradle plugin POM file, its not updating all dependency files on POM file. Updating POM file with required  dependency  fixed this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The error is expected because you're using `implementation` for your dependencies. When you're using `implementation` for dependencies of your library like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

each module using the library can't see the dependency because it's not compiled into the library. So, you need to add the dependency to your module like this:

```
dependencies {
    // assume this is the dependency before using the library
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.7'

    // you need to include the dependency from your library
    // to the module 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}
```

In case you want to use the same behavior as `compile`, you can use `api`.

Comment: I did not get it, do i need to use `api` instead of `implementation`  ?

Comment: It depends. If you're sure that you always use the same library and version, then you can use `api`. If you're not, use `implementation`.

Comment: I am sorry to get back to after long time, but thats what i am using in my gradle file know? using 'implementation' to load libs. sorry buy i still did not get your solution  for this issue.

Comment: what I meant is, when you're adding dependencies using `implementation` inside your library build.gradle, your app module can't see the them. You need to use `api`. Or add the same dependencies to your app module.